# TreeSet not arranging value in ascending order

Tags: java

I am trying to create a TreeSet to sort the strings which are inserted to be in an ascending order. I am using below code for entering values in TreeSet.

```
TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>();

ts.add("@Test0");
ts.add("@Test1");
ts.add("@Test2");
ts.add("@Test3");
ts.add("@Test10");
ts.add("@Test4");

System.out.println("Tree set :: "+ts);
```

**Output:**

> Tree set :: [@Test0, @Test1, @Test10, @Test2, @Test3, @Test4]

Comment: Because these are Strings, they are ordered lexicographically, or dictionary order, and not by numerical value.

Comment: That is ascending `lexical order`.

Comment: How do you want the strings to be ordered? Would all strings always start with `@Test`?

Comment: If you want it in a different ordering than lexical order, you will need to specify the ordering, and code up a `Comparator` that implements it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the Comparator to sort on the number part only.  This removes all but the number portion, converts that to an integer and sorts on that.

```
TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>(Comparator.comparing(
        s -> Integer.valueOf(s.replace("@Test", ""))));

ts.add("@Test0");
ts.add("@Test1");
ts.add("@Test2");
ts.add("@Test3");
ts.add("@Test10");
ts.add("@Test4");

System.out.println(ts);
```

prints

```
[@Test0, @Test1, @Test2, @Test3, @Test4, @Test10]
```

This works for the shown example.  You may need to modify it somewhat for more varied data.  But it demonstrates the idea.

Answer (score 4):

You've used the no-args TreeSet constructor. This means TreeSet will order its elements based on *natural order*. It's the way the objects compare themselves: It means the things you add must be of a type that implements `Comparable<Self>`. String does that: The String class is defined to implement `Comparable<String>`. However, the way strings compare themselves is lexicographically. 10 comes before 2 for the same reason that aa comes before b.

You have two routes available to fix this:

1. Don't put strings in there but some other object that implements Comparable and does it right. Perhaps a `class Thingie {String name; int idx;}`.
2. Pass a `Comparator` as first and only argument to your TreeSet class. Write code that determines that `@Test10` comes before `@Test2`. Then, TreeSet uses this comparator to determine ordering and won't use the one built into strings.

Comment: This solution that implies the use of a container class is better than others that  use substring, parseInt or replace in comparator. The expressions in comparators  are evaluated many times in a sort so must be very light.
From the example in the question seems that un alternative can mi a Set of Integers

Answer (score 1):

`@Test10` comes before `@Test2` because `1` comes before `2`. That's how the default ordering of `String` works (`String` implements the interface `Comparable` to do this sorting).

To solve your issue you need to provide a custom `Comparator` to the `TreeSet`, and do the comparison by parsing the integer within the string:

```
TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>(new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return Integer.parseInt(s1.substring(5)) - Integer.parseInt(s2.substring(5)); 
    }
});
```

The comparator can be constructed using the static convenience method:

```
TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(5))));
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Jems noted in the comment, strings are sorted lexichographically, so "@Test10" will come before "@Test2". If could however, supply a custom `Comparator` to define the order you need. E.g.,  if you know all the strings will have the form of "@Test" followed by a number, you could extract this number and sort accordingly:

```java
TreeSet<String> ts = 
    new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(5))));
```